# Area of polygon split by a line

Tags: postgis, polygon, query, definition-query

I need a query that return the area of two polygons that have been split by a line.

This is what I did so far:

```
SELECT ST_Area(ST_Split(surface.geom, limite_a.geom)) from surface,
limite_a   where surface.id = 945 and limite_a.id=123
```

Answer (score 9):

The [docs](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Split.html) specify that `ST_Split` returns a collection of geometries.  You can confirm this using some test data:

```
WITH rect AS (SELECT 'POLYGON ((0 0, 10 0, 10 1, 0 1, 0 0))'::geometry as geom),
     line AS (SELECT 'LINESTRING (3 0, 3 1)'::geometry as geom)

SELECT ST_GeometryType(ST_Split(rect.geom, line.geom)) FROM rect, line
-- returns 'ST_GeometryCollection'
```

As you've noticed, computing `ST_Area` on the `GeometryCollection` result gives the total area of the split polygons, which is the same area as your input polygon.  To get the area of the individual components of the split polygon, you need to deaggregate the `GeometryCollection` using [`ST_Dump`](http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/ST_Dump.html):

```
WITH rect AS (SELECT 'POLYGON ((0 0, 10 0, 10 1, 0 1, 0 0))'::geometry as geom),
     line AS (SELECT 'LINESTRING (3 0, 3 1)'::geometry as geom)

SELECT ST_Area((ST_Dump(ST_Split(rect.geom, line.geom))).geom) FROM rect, line
-- returns 3, 7
```

The extra parentheses around `ST_Dump` are necessary because this function actually returns a special composite type: `geometry_dump`.  You want to pull the geometry out of the geometry_dump, which you accomplish by wrapping the result of `ST_Dump` in parentheses and accessing the `.geom` field.  Check out the ST_Dump docs for some more examples of this.